# How to select and assign multiple entries into a array like variable in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I am new to sql. I want some thing like

```
DECLARE @VALID_ITEM_NUMBERS ITEM_NUMBER

SELECT @ITEM_NUMBERS = ITEM_NUMBER FROM [dbo].[ITEM] where IS_VALID = 1
```

(
here in the first line `ITEM_NUMBER` is a predefined type, 
and on the second line `ITEM_NUMBER` refers to a column (of type `ITEM_NUMBER`) in the table named `ITEM`. `IS_VALID` is also a column in `ITEM` table
)

But `SET` or `SELECT` returns only one value. I want `@VALID_ITEM_NUMBERS` to contain all the valid item numbers, like an array.

Is there any way to do this without crating a separate stored procedure?

Comment: Is it Sql server or MySql? Those are different products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one table variable to store all the values

declare @ITEM_NUMBERS table (ITEM_NUMBER int NOT NULL)

insert into @ITEM_NUMBERS(ITEM_NUMBER)

(select ITEM_NUMBER FROM [dbo].[ITEM] where IS_VALID = 1 )

select ITEM_NUMBER from @ITEM_NUMBERS

Comment: Both
 DECLARE (a)ITEM_NUMBERS table (ITEM_NUMBER int NOT NULL)

 SELECT (a)ITEM_NUMBERS = ITEM_NUMBER from ITEM

and

 DECLARE (a)ITEM_NUMBERS table (ITEM_NUMBER ITEM_NUMBER)

 SELECT (a)ITEM_NUMBERS = ITEM_NUMBER from ITEM

is giving syntax error 'must declare the scalar variable "(a)ITEM_NUMBERS"'.

(a) = at the rate

Comment: It is giving error "must declare the scalar variable "(a)ITEM_NUMBERS" when I try to assign the valid item numbers using the select query I mentioned.

Comment: I have expanded the query for your understanding